# Cake PHP 3.5 multiple pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have a media library where i load images and videos, both should have a pagination. So far it works and i can load e.g. the page 2,3... with ajax and replace the content for each entity.
Now the problem is the first page + the first- and prev- buttons if they point to the first page from each entity. Why? 
The created links look like :

- working one : http://www.xyz.de/media?image[page]=2
- not working : http://www.xyz.de/.media

This occurs in the image- and video-paginaton for the first page. 
What I am doing wrong? I read the Paginator-Component and the Paginator-Helper Doku 100 times and can firure it out.

I have my MediaController where I set up my paginator as follows :

```
public $paginate = [
    'Images'    => ['limit' => 10, 'scope' => 'image'],
    'Videos'    => ['limit' => 8, 'scope' => 'video'],
    'limit'     => 12
];
```

than in my controller-action i set the values :

```
$images = $this->paginate($imageTable->find('all',$image_options), ['scope' => 'image']);
$videos = $this->paginate($videosTable->find('all', $video_options), ['scope' => 'video']);
$this->set(compact('images', 'videos'));
```

in my view I use the PaginatorHelper to set e.g. the numbers like so

```
$paginator->numbers(['model' => 'Images'])
```